# i'm getting this error in react native for ios when adding firebase storage 'FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage-Swift.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

i'm getting this error in react native for ios when adding firebase storage 'FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage-Swift.h' file not found

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZSjC.png)

Libraries i'm using in react native
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.7.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^16.7.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.7.0",
"@react-native-firebase/storage": "^16.7.0",

My project podfile look like

```js
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseAuthInterop', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', :modular_headers => true
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true


target 'schooler' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => true,
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'schoolerTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```